# Using RegEx to Split the Url

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, regex

I want to Split the url into two part using RegEx. I have saved the xml response into datatable and iterate through the each row using foreach. When I use the datatable value for regEx only 0 will be available. When I use the array index 1 it give the following Exception.

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
```

The Following is gives and Exception.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ndt.Rows)
{
    string imgurl =row["image1"].ToString();

    String[] fimgurl = Regex.Split(imgurl, @"small/");
    String  simgurl = fimgurl[1];
}
```

The Following It's working without any issue.

```
foreach (DataRow row in ndt.Rows)
{
    //TextBox1.Text = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
    string imgurl ="http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/12/124356/124356a_hb_w_001.jpg";
    String[] fimgurl = Regex.Split(imgurl, @"small/");
    String  simgurl = fimgurl[1];
}
```

I Have saved  the same url as string in My Datatable. I couldn't find what's wrong with that. Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: Well `imgurl` obviously doesn't equal `http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/12/124356/124356a_hb_w_001.jpg`??

Answer (score 5):

> Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems. --Jamie Zawinski

```
var uri = new Uri("http://www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/12/124356/124356a_hb_w_001.jpg");

var firstPart = uri.Host + String.Concat(uri.Segments.Take(3));
  // returns: "www.hotelbeds.com/giata/small/"

var lastPart = String.Concat(uri.Segments.Skip(3));
  // returns: "12/124356/124356a_hb_w_001.jpg"
```

If you need the `http`, you can use `uri.Scheme`. Obviously just change `3` to some other number if you want to split in a different place.

Additionally you can search `uri.Segments` for the index of which directory you want if it changes.

Answer (score 1):

It can means only that

```
string imgurl =row["image1"].ToString();
```

not equals value, that you provides. Try to debug your code and find out what exactly value has your variable `imgurl`

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code.

The problem is that you have an url that don't contain "small/" in it. so the Split function return an array of length 1, so when you try to access the index 1 you have exception.

If you want more detail you have to post the content of ndt.

a simple way to debuf is to print the url to the console so you can see the url:

```
foreach (DataRow row in ndt.Rows)
            {
    string imgurl =row["image1"].ToString();
    Console.WriteLine(imgurl)
    String[] fimgurl = Regex.Split(imgurl, @"small/");
    String  simgurl = fimgurl[1];
}
```

Comment: there is no console in ASP.Net

Comment: use System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine instead

Comment: That also won't work in Asp.Net. This is HTTP, your thinking like a windows app. The only place you can write to is the HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

in your grid there may be images without `small/` in the url so better to add condition like below

```
if(fimgurl.Length >1)
      String  simgurl = fimgurl[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an error in column name:
in first variant you use `image1` column, in second variant you use `ImagePath` (in comment), maybe you must use `ImagePath` column like:

```
string imgurl = row["ImagePath"].ToString();
```